# How can i translate this "for" loop into a "while" loop?

Tags: c

I need to translate this little `for` loop into a `while` loop, how can i do this?

```
void count_the_numbers(int array[]){
printf("\n");
int i = -1;
while(i < 4){
    int count = 1;
    i++;

    for(int j=0; j < 5; j++){
        if(i != j && array[i] == array[j])
            count++;
    }
    printf("Number %d is %d times in this array/e\n", array[i], 
    conteggio);
}
}
```

This is another loop that gives me a different result than the previous one

Comment: You can lookup the definition of `for` loop. `for (A; B; C) { D;}` is identical with `A; while (B) {D; C; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Translating a `for` loop to a `while` loop is purely mechanical. Given any loop like this:

```c
for(w; x; y) {
    z;
}
```

It can be straightforwardly turned into this:

```c
w;
while(x) {
    z;
    y;
}
```

The only complicating factor, which doesn't apply in your example, is that if the `for` loop used `continue` anywhere in the body, you'd need to duplicate `y` to before each occurrence of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = j-1;
while (i>=0) {
    printf("%d\n", array[i--]);
}
```